# Bind List to comboBox in C#

Tags: c#, generics, combobox

I have three comboBoxes in a WinForm. To load those combos with data I created three methods.
Two of these methods looks like this:

```
private void cmbLoadSubjects(List<Subject> subjects)
    {
        BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = subjects;

        cmbSubjects.DataSource = source;
        cmbSubjects.DisplayMember = "name";
        cmbSubjects.ValueMember = "id";
    }

private void cmbLoadTeachers(List<Teacher> teachers)
    {
        BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = teachers;

        cmbTeachers.DataSource = source;
        cmbTeachers.DisplayMember = "name";
        cmbTeachers.ValueMember = "id";
    }
```

The idea is to display the subject's name and the teacher's name in the combos.

[image: Combo box showing teachers]

Given the fact that these methods are very similar, I tried to create a generic method that can load all the combos. So I came up with this:

```
private void cargarCombo<T>(ComboBox combo, List<T> data, string displayMember, string valueMember)
    {
        BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = data;

        combo.DataSource = source.DataSource;
        cmbEstadoAsistencia.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        cmbEstadoAsistencia.ValueMember = valueMember;
    }
```

If I use this method to load my combos, it only works fine in one of the combos. In the other combos it shows the typical"WorkspaceName.ClassName".
[image: Combo box of teachers when using generic method]

I tried loading teachers and then tried loading subjects in the only combo that works fine and it showed what it was supposed to show:

[image: Teacher loaded with generic method]
[image: Subjects loaded with generic method]

But when I try to load the other combos using this generic method, despite the class of the objects, I get "Workspace.Teacher", "Workspace.Subject".

I compared the values of the properties of the three combos trying to find something different in order to discover what could be causing this behavior and they only differ in their name and position.

I tried creating a new combo and loading lists of different class of objects but the problems is still there.

One curious thing is that it all works fine if I use the methods I showed you at the beggining of the question. I mean, I could just make use of those methods and forget about this stupid problem, but I'm curious.. I just don't get why the generic method only works fine in one combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is that I'm an idiot sometimes:

```
private void cargarCombo<T>(ComboBox combo, List<T> data, string displayMember, string valueMember)
{
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
    source.DataSource = data;

    combo.DataSource = source.DataSource;
    cmbEstadoAsistencia.DisplayMember = displayMember;
    cmbEstadoAsistencia.ValueMember = valueMember;
}
```

**cmbEstadoAsistencia** should be change to **combo**

I was hardcoding the name of one of the comboBoxes. 
I'm sorry for posting garbage :(

Answer (score 0):

Your error could be here

```
combo.DataSource = source.DataSource;
```

Change that to

```
combo.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both ways before posting and got the same result

Comment: Did you test this generic with the data is already working on combo is working ? Tried subject or teacher on a combo is working but with generic ?

Comment: Your problem is that you are not setting correctly the `displayMember` and  `valueMember`. I have a program where I do use that and if I remove or write that wrongly, I have the same error as you, that `namespace.blablabla`. Try hardcoding that part and if it works, you know your error is there and tell me.

Comment: Thanks again. That wasn't the problem, but when I was about to do what you told me, I realized I hardcoded the name of one of the combos in my generic method. That's why only one of the three combos was working. 
Thanks for your good intentions :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "Subject" class needs to have its get and set in its attributes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30893246)